# Passing string[] from batch file (which contains double quotes ") to powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, cakebuild

I have a powershell script which has a `string[]` parameter and try to pass value to this from batch file

**PowerShell Script**

```
[string[]]$ScriptArgs
```

**Batch File**

```
powershell -File Foobar.ps1 -ScriptArgs -versn="""1.0.0.0""",pattern="""FooBar.*"""
```

(3 Quotes - For escaping/showing 1 quote)

But no matter what I do `Write-Host $ScriptArgs.Count` prints `1`

I want the variable to receive 2 elements

`[0]` will be `-versn="1.0.0.0"`
`[1]` will be `-pattern="FooBar.*"`

---

In batch file, I even tried setting variables individually

```
set @sArgs = -versn="""1.0.0.0"""
set @sArgs = %sArgs%;-pattern="""FooBar.*"""
powershell -File Foobar.ps1 -ScriptArgs %sArgs%
```

but the console somehow runs as if the variable is not created and run it as

```
powershell -File Foobar.ps1 -ScriptArgs
```

and throws error

> Missing an argument for parameter 'ScriptArgs'. Specify a parameter of type `System.String[]` and try again

What should I change to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**When calling a PowerShell script from from a *batch file* (from `cmd.exe`) *with `-File`*, there is *no*  way to *directly* pass an array of values to a PowerShell *array* parameter:**

- If you specify the array values without spaces, they are considered a SINGLE element; e.g.:

  - `one,two,three` becomes a SINGLE array element
- If you do use spaces, the *trailing commas become part of the arguments*, and *only the FIRST value is bound to the array parameter*:

  - `one, two, three` - `one,` - including the trailing `,` - becomes the *only* array element, `two,` and `three,` are considered *separate* arguments.

The **workarounds** are to:

- **Either**: **use `-Command`** to invoke the script - see bottom section.
- **Or, with `-File`**, declare the parameter differently and pass arguments differently:

  - decorate the array parameter with **attribute
    `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]`**
  - and to **pass the array elements as *individual, space-separated arguments*, *without their parameter name***.

In your case:

- Declare the parameter:

  ```
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
  [string[]] $ScriptArgs
  ```
- Invoke the script with *separate, space-separate* arguments *not preceded by the parameter name* to bind them as an array to `$ScriptArgs`:

  ```
  powershell -File Foobar.ps1 "-versn=\"1.0.0.0\"" "pattern=\"FooBar.*\""
  ```

  - Note the quoting:

    - Each argument *as a whole* is enclosed in `"..."` - this isn't strictly necessary, but guards against `-`-prefixed values such as `-version` being mistaken for parameter names.
    - `"` chars. to be retained as *literals* are `\`-escaped (which contrasts with the `` ` ``-escaping that must be used from *within* PowerShell).

The **inherent limitations** of this approach:

- The approach **doesn't support *multiple* array parameters**, because only *one* can be decorated with `ValueFromRemainingArguments`.
- You **cannot pass any *other* arguments *positionally*** (i.e., you must precede arguments to pass to other parameters with their parameter name).

---

**Alternative: Using `-Command` instead of `-File`:**

```
powershell -command "./Foobar.ps1 '-versn=\"1.0.0.0\"', '-pattern=\"FooBar.*\"'"
```

Note:

- **What you pass to `-Command` is treated as a piece of PowerShell code** - whether you pass a *single* argument or *multiple* ones - in the latter case, they are simply *concatenated* with spaces and the *result* is then interpreted as PowerShell code.
- The implications are:

  - To execute a script in the current directory, you must refer to it with a *path* (`.\`) - in order to execute it.

    - Additionally, if the script path contains whitespace or other shell metacharacters, you must quote it and invoke it via `&`, the call operator; e.g., `& '.\Foo Bar.ps1'`
  - You can pass array arguments as usual, *except* that `"` chars. must again be escaped as `\"`, not `` `" ``.
  - Also note that again the arguments are quoted *as a whole* (too), which in this is case *required* to prevent PowerShell from interpreting `-versn` and `-pattern` as parameter names.

    - Given that the overall command must be passed inside `"..."`, performing the embedded quoting with `"`, which still possible, is quite awkward, because you then have to *combine* `\`- and `` ` ``-escaping; e.g., `` \"-pattern=`\"FooBar.*`\"\" ``
  - Generally, be aware that all usual PowerShell parsing rules apply, so that, for instance, to use a *literal* `$`, you must escape it as `` `$ ``.