# How to pass arguments via powershell scripts

Tags: powershell

I've got a NodeJS file and I run it with a Windows PowerShell script (run.ps1) that contains this line:

```
node ./main.js
```

I would like to pass command line arguments directly when I run the ps script in this way:

```
./run.ps1 -a firstargument -b secondargument etc...
```

This method doesn't work. How can I do?

UPDATE: The solution is write `node ./main.js $args` inside `.ps1` script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass command line arguments to a Node.js program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

If your `.ps1` script doesn't explicitly declare parameters, use the **[automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) variable** to pass all arguments it received through to your `node` script:

```
node ./main.js $args
```

---

PowerShell scripts (and functions) may explicitly declare parameters to bind arguments passed to them on invocation, using a `param()` block - see the conceptual [about_Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scripts#parameters-in-scripts) help topic.

**In the absence of parameter declarations,<sup>[1]</sup> arguments are reported via the automatic `$args` variable**, which is a regular PowerShell **array** of type `[object[]]`, whose first element (`$args[0]`) is the first argument.<sup>[2]</sup>

Note:

- Passing an array such as `$args` to an ***external program*** passes the elements as *individual arguments*, which is appropriate (given that external program CLIs generally have no concept of *arrays*).
- By contrast, if you invoke a ***PowerShell* command** with `$args`, the array is passed as a *single* argument, i.e. the array is passed *as a whole*, as the first and only positional argument.

  - To properly relay `$args` to PowerShell commands, use **`@args`**, which (due to `$args`-specific magic) even works with *named* arguments (e.g., `-foo bar`). This technique is known as [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)

---

<sup>[1] Technically, as long as your script or function is not an *advanced* one, `$args` can be *combined* with explicit parameter declarations, in that `$args` then only contains *extra* arguments, i.e. those that weren't bound to declared parameters.

By contrast, the preferable [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) scripts and functions (cmdlet-like, those that have a `[CmdletBinding()]` and/or `[Parameter()]` attributes) do not support extra arguments at all, and report an *error*. Supporting extra arguments in advanced scripts/functions requires declaration of a catch-all parameter, via the `[Parameter()` attribute's `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959328/45375) for an example.</sup>

<sup>[2] That is, unlike in C programs, for instance, `$args` doesn't also include the running script's name or path, as the first element.</sup>